# Filter out messages from a ros bag

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to filter out some "bad messages" from my rosbags. I'm using the C++ rosbag API. Should I open the bagfile in read mode and republish the good messages and record them in another bag using 'rosbag record'? Or is there a way to modify the bag in place when it's in read or write mode?

I've gone through the C++ API of rosbag a bit, I couldn't find examples similar to what I want to do. Thanks.

Update:
Is there a method to find out the list of topics that are present in the bag and other statistics through the API?
Is there a way to find out which topic, a particular message instance is from while iterating over them in a `boost foreach` loop as shown in the example [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240829/filter-out-messages-from-a-ros-bag/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2016-08-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened the bag file in read mode and used the `rosbag::View` class to look at each topic individually. Then saved all the messages into an object I'm more comfortable with (`std::vector` for instance). It's based off of the example on [this page in the Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api).

And so perform all operations/logic on the more familiar data structure and then open a new bag file in write mode into which you can add all the required messages.

This is a roundabout way to do it, but I couldn't find a method in the API to: 1. find out which topic a particular message is coming from (if I were to view all topics at once in a single `for` loop) or 2. modify the messages in a particular topic in place or query what topics are present in a bag and other things like that.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bit easier with python:

```
import rosbag

with rosbag.Bag('output.bag', 'w') as outbag:
    for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('input.bag').read_messages():
        if topic == "/tf" and msg.transforms:
            outbag.write(topic, msg, msg.transforms[0].header.stamp)
        else:
            outbag.write(topic, msg, msg.header.stamp if msg._has_header else t)
```

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-02**:
Yeah, I came across this on the wiki. This doesn't help though because I specifically want to use the C++ API. I figured out a roundabout way to do it (based off of the [C++ API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api) which I have shared in my answer).

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-06-06**:
More specific link where you got this code from: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2020-06-28**:
I recently wrote `ros_readbagfile`, and this tutorial on how to use it, here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/reading%20msgs%20from%20a%20bag%20file. See my answer here too: https://answers.ros.org/question/240829/filter-out-messages-from-a-ros-bag/?answer=240861#post-id-240861.